# Let $N$ be any four digit number, $N=x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4$. Find the maximum value of $\frac{N}{x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Let $N$ be any four digit number say $x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4$. Then maximum value of $\frac{N}{x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4}$is equal to

(A) 1000

(B) $\frac{1111}{4}$

(C) $800$

(D) none of these

My approach is as follow $N=1000x_1+100x_2+10x_3+x_4$

$T=\frac{1000x_1+100x_2+10x_3+x_4}{x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4}$

$T=\frac{999x_1+99x_2+9x_3}{x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4}+1$

Not able to proceed from here

Comment: An informal (i.e. intuitive, somewhat invalid) approach is that when you start with a baseline of $~x_2 = x_3 = x_4 = 0,~$ it seems clear (at least to me) that increasing the value of (for example) $~x_2~$ has a more significant effect on the denominator, than it does on the numerator.  This intuition holds across various values for $~x_1.$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is (A). First, we can note that
$$
\frac{1000}{1+0+0+0} = 1000,
$$
thus we rule out (B), (C) immediately. It only remains to find out whether we can achieve a value greater than 1000. But we can note that
\begin{align}
\frac{N}{x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4} &> 1000\\
N &> 1000(x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4)\\
1000x_1 + 100x_2 + 10x_3 + x_4 &> 1000(x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4)
\end{align}
but it is clear that the last line cannot be true since the $x_i$'s are $\geq 0$, and in particular, $x_1\geq 1$ since $N$ is four digits. Thus the answer must be (A).

Answer (score 3):

> $T=\frac{1000x_1+100x_2+10x_3+x_4}{x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4}$

> $T=\frac{999x_1+99x_2+9x_3}{x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4}+1$

Now $x_4$ is a free variable, we want $T$ to be max, so let $x_4=0$

$$T=\frac{999x_1+99x_2+9x_3}{x_1+x_2+x_3}+1=1+9\left(\frac{110x_1+10x_2}{x_1+x_2+x_3}+1\right)$$

Now, $x_3$ is free variable, so let $x_3=0$, and keep going, can you proceed from here?

Answer (score 1):

**Hints.**

- Check that the value $1000$ can be obtained
- Compute $1110-T$ in terms of the $x_i's$ and show it is non negative (remember that $x_i\geq 0$).